# GIMP how can I do what I used to do? Cut and paste or move a selection, delete a selection, and write into a selection near an area I've just moved

Tags: gimp

This used to be fairly simple, I could do what I wanted and didn't have any problems. Now I have downloaded a chart with circles and numbers under the circles. I want to:

1. Delete some circles and numbers,
2. Rearrange other circles and numbers by moving them to another place on the sheet,
3. Move just the circle and type my own number under it and
4. If I copy and paste the circle and number then I want to delete that circle and number from its original place and
5. Delete the number under the circle and type in a new number.

I have been working on this for many, many hours over a couple weeks, sometimes something will work and I've even written down what I did, but I try it again and it won't work. In fact new problems arise. I have submitted questions before but I haven't been able to decipher the answers. One time my question was deemed a duplicate and I was told to find the previous answer but I got all tangled up in replies and nothing made sense to me.

I am an old lady that can figure some things out on my computer but when I can't, I get easily confused by complicated answers or especially when what I'm told to do won't work. I would appreciate answers in simple terms, and even better in a list, do this and this and then this. I know there is something about layers but I've still to figure out much more than that.

I was asked to attach a screenshot but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I was told to cut and paste and that didn't work. I have a little program called Snipping Tool but I couldn't find a place to attach the file. I saw "Images" above on the bar but when I click on it, it doesn't make sense to me. I have spent so much time on this and I hope someone can help and not give up on me. Thank you.